# UITableViewCell.ImageView.image Compare UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

I am comparing cell.imageView.image with UIImage as below code.

Please refer below Code

```
    UIImage *imgOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"One"];

    if([customCell.imageView.image isEqual: imgOne]){
          NSLog(@"Right Image");
    }
```

While debugging, I write as `po [customCell.imageView.image isEqual imgOne]`, but it always returns as 'nil'.

Can anyone tell me how to compare this or proper way to compare?

Comment: :Tane prob che la? su thyu kahe solve kari apu.

Comment: The method you used should work. That is the proper way to compare images. Your debugging result should return true or false, not nil, so something else must be wrong. Try logging imgOne and also customCell.imageView.image to see what they give (put that log just above the line with your if statement, wherever that is).

Comment: @Manthan :- Ha bhai.. Problem 6... Check j nath thatu. each and every time e condition nil return kare 6..

Comment: @rdelmar :- Thank you for suggestion, I tried but its not working.

Comment: @ShreyanshShah: Still prob??? Evu hoy to chat room ma ay solve kari apu...

Comment: @Manthan :- Thank you bhai. Solve thai gayu....

Comment: @ShreyanshShah: Ok cheers then nd belated happy birthday jenny...

Comment: @Manthan :- Thanks a lot. Bhai.. This is not WA. Come on WA on on chat room. Here we cant chat like this.

Comment: @ShreyanshShah: Please give the answer to us so that can be helpful to anyone in future. Please post what was wrong in your code if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63328/discussion-between-shreyansh-shah-and-manthan).

Comment: @Manthan :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224347/ui-issue-in-version-7-1 Please check this and give me ans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you matain the "image one" as a member var.(1)
And set the cell's image this value.(2)
Then you can compare using those two pointers.(3)
See this code:

```
//1
self.imgOne  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"One"];  
//2  
customCell.imageView.image=self.imgOne   
//3  
if(customCell.imageView.image == self.imgOne)
   {}
```

Comment: so simple and quick. I think converting to nsdata is overkill

Answer (score 5):

Generally `UIImageView` can not store file name of image but it store only `UIImage` so, it is not possible to get file name of image which you add in `UIImageView`.

Thats way if you want to compare only image file name then it is not possible to compare it.

But If you want to compare two `UIImage` object then

```
UIImage *secondImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

NSData *imgData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageView.image);
NSData *imgData2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(secondImage);

BOOL isCompare =  [imgData1 isEqualToData:imgData2];
if(isCompare)
{
  NSLog(@"Image View contains image.png");
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"Image View doesn't contains image.png");
}
```

Comment: I ll try inform u soon.

Comment: :- Thank you for valuable time. This is working in demo project but not in my original app..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **Imageview** I tried with **Button**

And than i Check as below

```
    if([cell.button.currentImage isEqual: [UIImage imagenamed:"Your Imagenem"]]){
NSLog(@"Right Image");

}
```

It works fine..

Thank you.