# How to compare two UIImage in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using the method given below

IBOutlet UIImageView *imgViewCheck;

```
- (IBAction)clkCheckUncheck:(id)sender {
    if (imgViewCheck.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"]) {
        imgViewCheck.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    } else {
        imgViewCheck.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"];
    }
}
```

It is working in up to iOS7 but not working in iOS8

Comment: I dont think the method above could compare the UIImage, since both of these are different instance. The == operator only compare the address of the two objects and if both the object are the same instance then the == returns true. If you need to compare the image, you need to check that each byte in the image has same content./

Comment: this is generally a bad idea and it can fail with ios7, too. Better use imgViewCheck.tag or something like that to store the state of the imageview.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate answered by [This SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26439315/451475)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please compare NSData object instead of comparing UIImage Object.

```
-(BOOL)firstimage:(UIImage *)image1 isEqualTo:(UIImage *)image2 {
    NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
    NSData *data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image2);

    return [data1 isEqualToData:data2];
}
```

Comment: Actually use `isEqualToData:` instead of `isEqualTo:`. Essentially a duplicate of [This SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26439315/451475)

Answer (score 7):

I'd not rely on comparing image property with address returned by UIImage method (it could be newly allocated block I suppose).

If you really need to compare if data(image) is same you could use something like:

```
UIImage* checkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
NSData *checkImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(checkImage);
NSData *propertyImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgViewCheck.image);
if ([checkImageData isEqualToData:propertyImageData]) {
  //do sth
}
```

where possible I'd prefer to keep state/imageId in a variable for comparison purposes

Comment: /* The Proper answer should be
    UIImage* checkImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    NSData *checkImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(checkImage);
    NSData *propertyImageData =UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imageview.image);
    if ([checkImageData isEqualToData:propertyImageData]) {
        //do sth
    }