# UI Issue in version 7.1

Tags: ios, ios7

I am developing app for iPad with greater than 7.0 version.

I am facing annoying issue regarding UI. When I run app in iOS version with 7.1 it display as below:

[image: Images 1]

[image: Image 2]

I can access the buttons, textfield and all, but can't get background image, button background images of any controls.

I also run in simulator and same problem I get in it, but after reset the simulator, it's running fine. Now the question is, what about device?

When I run same app in different device with different iOS version like 8.0 and above. It's running perfectly.

Comment: I also tried with simulator same problem i get in it. But after reset simulator, Its running fine.. But what about device.?

Comment: Have you set any userdfaults then you have to reset your simulator. Please test on real device with ios 7.1 and 8.0 and then let me know what ossurs?

Comment: Dear... I already reset simulator. But in real device, how can i solve this problem. Each and every time i cant reset device.

Comment: @Manthan :- This is running perfectly fine other devices. But dint run in iPad Mini with 7.1 OS version..  In iPad Mini only, i found this type of Screen or UI or bug.

Comment: @ShreyanshShah: What is the bug? Both the screenshots you have shown are different. Not of a single screen

Comment: @Manthan :- These are the Screen Shot iPad Mini with iOS7.1 version.. In other device, already working file... In forgt pwd popup Screen shot , We cant see Button with images. In first Screen We can see on Labels, no images..

Comment: Try to run in ios7 simulator of iPad. If it is fine with that then that is the bug in os 7.1 i guess. Or else without your code i can not say much about this. In the end it doesn't work at all then create a demo xib and just try to give images to that on buttons and all and check in iPad mini. If it works then replace it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65961/discussion-between-shreyansh-shah-and-manthan).